# Include latest version of spring and hibernate in project using maven

Tags: maven

How to include latest version of spring and hibernate in project using maven, what all dependencies are needed to be added in pom file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create pom.xml file like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
 <groupId>com.test</groupId>  
 <artifactId>SpringHibernateAnnotations</artifactId>  
 <packaging>war</packaging>  
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
 <name>SpringHibernateAnnotations Maven Webapp</name>  
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  

 <properties>  
  <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>  
  <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>  
  <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>  
  <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>  
  <context.path>SpringHibernateAnnotations</context.path>  
 </properties>  


 <build>  
  <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>  

  <plugins>  
   <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->  
   <plugin>  
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
    <configuration>  
     <source>${jdk.version}</source>  
     <target>${jdk.version}</target>  
    </configuration>  
   </plugin>  
  </plugins>  
 </build>  
 <dependencies>  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>  
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>  
   <version>${log4j.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  

  <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>  
   <version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>  
   <version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  

  <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
   <version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  

  <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>  
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  

  <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
   <version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  

  <dependency>  
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>  
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>  
   <version>1.2</version>  
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>  
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>  
   <version>5.1.6</version>  
  </dependency>  


 </dependencies>  
</project>
```

You can change version according to your requirements.

Comment: Nice! If you were using properties for the other 3rd party libraries, it would be even nicer. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Maven Central Search](http://search.maven.org), search for Spring and Hibernate and find the latest versions.